# How can I use MySQL CASE inside SET without it being destructive?

Tags: mysql

I have many fields that I need to mass replace without destroying other data in that column.

If I run:

```
UPDATE ospos_items AS a
INNER JOIN ospos_items AS b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
SET a.custom7 = 'Detective Novels'
WHERE a.custom7 = 'DN'
AND a.custom3 = 'English Literature';
```

The Update is properly non-destructive.  But if I run the following code in an effort to combine queries:

```
UPDATE ospos_items AS a
INNER JOIN ospos_items AS b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
SET a.custom7 = CASE
WHEN a.custom7 = 'DN' THEN 'Detective Novels'
WHEN a.custom7 = 'HF' THEN 'Historical Fiction'
WHEN a.custom7 = 'HUM' THEN 'Humor'
WHEN a.custom7 = 'NOV' THEN 'Novels'
WHEN a.custom7 = 'YA' THEN 'Young Adults'
END
WHERE a.custom3 IN('English Literature');
```

It sets all values in that column to NULL not found in the CASE. For example, some of the fields in that column have already been converted.  How can I make my second query non-destructive to values not found in the CASE statement?

Comment: You have to think about `ELSE` condition for `CASE`.

Comment: Use an ELSE, but also include a WHERE.

Comment: Do you actually need that INNER JOIN?

Comment: @Strawberry the first query requires it to make the update non-destructive. Otherwise I would have needed a WHERE IN clause that includes the item_id of each row I wanted to update, but you can't do subqueries like that with SET. I assumed that the 2nd query would also need it for the same reason but perhaps I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Add `ELSE a.custom7` to the `CASE` expression. Then it will keep the same value if none of the `WHEN` conditions match.
2. Add `AND a.custom7 IN ('DN', 'HF', 'HUM', 'NOV', 'YA')` to the `WHERE` clause. Then it will only update the rows where one of the `CASE` expressions matches.

BTW, when you're testing the same column in every `WHEN` clause, you can use the simpler:

```
CASE a.custom7
WHEN 'DN' THEN 'Detective Novels'
WHEN 'HF' THEN 'Historical Fiction'
...
END
```

Comment: I chose option 1 and it worked well.  Thank you. +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `ELSE` clause to the `CASE` expression so that the value remains the same when it is not one of the ones you want to change:

```
UPDATE ospos_items AS a
INNER JOIN ospos_items AS b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
SET a.custom7 = CASE
WHEN a.custom7 = 'DN' THEN 'Detective Novels'
WHEN a.custom7 = 'HF' THEN 'Historical Fiction'
WHEN a.custom7 = 'HUM' THEN 'Humor'
WHEN a.custom7 = 'NOV' THEN 'Novels'
WHEN a.custom7 = 'YA' THEN 'Young Adults'
ELSE a.custom7
END
WHERE a.custom3 IN('English Literature');
```

Comment: @Strawberry it's not required - as Barmar points out you can do one or the other to resolve the issue.

Comment: But including it is likely to be faster

Comment: Also note tthat you can use the less verbose CASE statement here (as per Barmar's suggestion)

Comment: @Strawberry using the `WHERE` clause renders the `ELSE` redundant. It's not clear to me that it's faster as it requires checking the value of `a.custom7` twice (once for the `WHERE` and once for the `CASE`) as opposed to only once when you use the `ELSE` clause.

Comment: @Strawberry everything you point out is why Barmar's answer has 4 upvotes and mine only 1...

Comment: Well actually, on a test on a dense data set with a composite index on ca. 12000 rows, it took the same time with and without the WHERE clause, so fair enough - although I'm a bit unclear about what the INNER JOIN is really doing in this instance.

Comment: @Strawberry that's interesting - I wonder how the optimisation is made to make them take the same time. You're right on the inner join, I suspect this can't be the entire query...